# In AnyLogic, how do you keep consistency when switching between ViewAreas of different sizes?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

When we make ViewAreas of different sizes, we see inconsistencies in the menu bar and extra space while running the medal.
The problem in displayed in the images below.

- Normal size viewArea
  [image]
- Big viewArea show inconsistency.
  [image]

How do I make different-sized ViewAreas look consistent while running?

It is implemented in the Wholesale Warehouse example model, but how?
Attaching the screenshots of the example model below.

- Different view area sizes

[image]

- No inconsistency while running the model

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You keep the view areas at the same size and adjust the other elements

Comment: In the Wholesale Warehouse example, they manage to do it. But I am unable to figure out how. I am adding screenshots of the example model above.

Comment: Clearly, they simply change the size of the menu text objects, I can even see it on your screenshots: larger view area menu text is larger than the text in the smaller view area. You can do that as well but it is a pain. Much easier to simply set all view areas to the same resolution upfront and go with that